# How to delete all files inside a specific folder using php

Tags: javascript, php

How can I delete all the files in a folder using php/javascript. For example, this is what I am trying to do in php:
using unlink function

Comment: What files, on the client or on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
array_map('unlink', glob("some/dir/*.txt"));
```

this will delete all txt files in the directory for example

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the files including hidden files

```
$files = glob('some/directory/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file){
if(is_file($file))
  unlink($file);
}
```